# Can I filter out Windows only games when using the Steam client on a Mac?

Tags: steam, macos

I recently got myself a Macbook Pro and promptly installed Steam on it (mainly, so that I could play the [Binding of Isaac](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binding-of-isaac)).

While I have quite a few games that are compatible with OS X in my Steam library, the majority are not, and still they are pointlessly displayed when I view my library from my Mac.

Is there any way for me to only see the Mac-friendly games I have in my library? I have quite a few, and doing this manually would be quite tedious, not to mention I would then have to rely on my memory to remember which games are actually available for my Mac.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

When looking at your library, select Mac Games from the drop down next to the search function.

[image: Needs moar freehand circles, I know.]

Comment: Too bad they don't have this feature on Windows.  Of course, part of the problem is that Civilization 4 has separate PC and Mac entries, or else I wouldn't need a filter for Windows-only.