# Filter games to Mac-compatible on Steam

Tags: steam, macos

Is it possible to filter out Windows only games while on Windows?  I'm getting a Mac soon for work purposes and I want to know what games I own will natively support Mac without having to buy Windows again.

I read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34270/can-i-filter-out-windows-only-games-when-using-the-steam-client-on-a-mac) question but the issue with that is it only works while on a Mac, I am on a windows for now and cannot use the Mac client until I actually get the Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Steam DB](https://steamdb.info/) allows you to filter your games by the systems `macOS`, `Linux`, and `Steam Deck`.

Also, if steam is running on macOS, there is an Apple logo in the Library to filter only Mac-compatible games.

Comment: Where exactly did you find that filter? It has all kind of handy stats, but don't see the mentioned filters anywhere?

Comment: Under Find Games, filter by macOS (Apple Silicon) https://steamdb.info/instantsearch/?refinementList%5Boslist%5D%5B0%5D=macOS%20%28Apple%20Silicon%29

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not.  I have created a Steam category called "Windows Only" and tag all of the non-Mac games with that.  However, I still have to occasionally go through the list and remove the tag, as Mac versions of games can appear without fanfare.  (I do this by scrolling through the full list on a Mac and seeing if the Install button appears or not.)

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but i have actually found a way to filter it no matter what OS you're on.

Answer (score 0):

This does not give you exactly what you are looking for, but it is the closest I can come up with, without coding something up.  If you go into the Steam web store, and select Mac OSX, you can browse the catalog and see what you have.  It will show you which games you already, as seen in the screenshot:

[image: steam store image]

As you can see here, I'm on the Steam store website, so it does not matter what OS I'm running.  I selected "Games" -> "Mac OS X" from the main menu, then sorted by game reviews, and you can see I have 4 of the 7 most popular games that are available for the Mac.

I'm fulling willing to admit this is not an easy way to get a complete list, but it should help you have some idea what you can be playing when you kill Windows.

Answer (score 0):

- Open *Steam*
- Select the *[Store](https://store.steampowered.com/)*
- *Search the store* for anything, we want to see the filters

  [image: Steam: Search the store]
- Use the filters to the right of the search results: ***Narrow by OS***

  [image: Steam: Narrow by OS]
- Tweak your search

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Even though not the most practical, it is an alternative and viable addition.

Comment: @Joachim the original question was about filtering games I own (in my library), this answer is for filtering the store's search. I do see now that the original question from 6 years ago is a little vague.